# 2012 Ford Fiesta overheating

Tags: ford, fiesta

Hello so let me start by saying I am not a mechanic but more of a tinker. With that out of the way, my car overheated on the highway and the thin head gasket blew, I replaced the head gasket in my 2012 Ford Fiesta SEL by myself and with the help of a YouTube series which walked me through everything. Well the car starts up, before it wouldn’t at all. Now the problem is it is overheating. I run it and drive for about 10-15 minutes and the temperature gets up to about 220-230. I have replaced the thermostat, timing belt, tensioner, CPS’s, and serpentine belt. I do not believe it is the water pump since coolant is circulating through the engine and back into the overflow tank. It could be the temperature sensor but when I hook up the OBD I can read the temperature fine so that would be off if it was sending bad signals to the ecu. I do not believe it’s the radiator since I had no issues with it before the head gasket blew. My theory is that I have a warped head or the head gasket blew again because it did overheat minorly when I test ran it, or I did not torque the head bolts well enough. Any other theories you can suggest from experience?

Comment: Yes, you may not have bled or burped it correctly or sufficiently.

Comment: Indeed. I agree with Mike. Did you let the gasses out of the cooling system? A coolant flush would suffice, sans any chemicals.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue that created the overheating problem initially?

Comment: @jwh20 I did, the overflow hose had broken before so I’ve replaced it/

Comment: @solar mike well I’ve tried to burp it however these fiestas are notorious for being difficult to burp. I’ve left the coolant tank cap off for 10 minutes I’m not sure what else I can do to burp it

Comment: You said the temperature read on the scanner looks fine, but does it agree with the dashboard indicator? Is the cooling fan turning on? When it does, the temperature drops or keeps high/rising? You may want to specify what engine is fitted in your car. FYI, in Brazil, Fiestas come with the Zetec Rocam engine, which I think is exclusive for our market.